# Dynamically injected CSS @keyframes not working for Android

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, css

I have an issue while injecting dynamically my keyframes in the DOM in javascript.

I'm injecting the keyframes in the DOM like this:

`javascript`

```
    var keyframes = '@keyframes traveler { ';
        keyframes += '0% { left: 0; } ';
        keyframes += '100% { left: '+travelerPosition+'px; } ';
        keyframes += '}';

    $('#traveler').empty().append(keyframes); //This is the <style> tag

    $('.traveler').removeClass('animated').addClass('animated'); //This is the div that needs to be animated
```

Every time the `travelerPosition` has a new value, this javascript code is executed.

`css (sass)`

```
.traveler {
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;

    &.animated {
        animation-name: traveler;
        animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
        animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    }
}
```

It works fine on my computer, tested on Chrome and Safari. It also work fine on iPhone and iPad. But I have an issue with Android devices, the animation doesn't want to run at all and I can't find the reason why.

Do you have any suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: The `.traveler` div doesn't have the `animated` class at the launch time.

Comment: also, what browser are you using? Android stock browser needs -webkit-keyframes

Comment: I am running it with Cordova on an Android 5 device. Do I need the -webkit prefix?

Comment: just check.... I write the keyframes with and without prefix, older android browsers work with webkit while Chrome browser works without

Comment: You're right, it works fine while adding the `-webkit` prefix! Thank you!
FYI it works without prefix when it's in the CSS file, but doesn't work when it's injected.